# Hiding Fields or Disabling Them?

Tags: custom-fields, fields

Can you disable or hide fields in the Individual window?

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the "Summary" tab when viewing a contact?  If so, you can do so by installing the [Contact Layout Editor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contact-layout-editor) extension.

Note also that many (not all) fields can be disabled from **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Display Preferences**.